# Can I run a ser al cable from a 125amp breaker to a sub panel?

Tags: wiring, installation

I’m trying to run the wire from the meter to a sub panel which is like 20ft.
I’ve never wired a ser Al wire to a breaker before so I’m trying to see if it’s possible.

Comment: What wire size is your cable or have you not purchased it yet?

Comment: Is this the *only* panel? Or is it actually a "meter main" with multiple breakers in it and this is a feed from the lugs? Or is it actually a "meter main" with multiple breakers in it and this is a feed from a 125A breaker? Need more details as it does not make sense as written.

Comment: Also, why are you using cable so fat for a 125A  (or 100A for that matter) circuit?

Comment: If this is NOT a feed from a meter to a **main panel**, 2AWG aluminum can only be used at 90A, not 100A, for a **sub-panel** but since the wire and breaker size have both been given as inconsistent numbers an [edit] of the question to make it all consistent and clear (and provide some pictures while you're at it) would be advisable

Answer (score 0):

Is it ***possible***? Sure. Most breakers are sized to take the size wire required for their ampacity in Aluminum, or several sizes larger. Since you have not specified the breaker make/model or the cable size that can't be verified in your case, but it's certainly possible.

You will, of course, require a suitable torque driver to make the connections properly to code by using the manufacturer specified torques.

Is it the best option? Not enough info to say. If the cable route is subject to damage, you might be better off running conduit and THHN or XHHW wires rather than cable, if you'll need conduit anyway for damage protection.

Comment: Oh didn’t see this, the wire is Southwire 1-ft 2-2-2-4 Stranded Aluminum Ser and the breaker is a Siemens 100amp breaker

Comment: @JustinMejia -- you said it was 4/0-4/0-4/0-2/0 in a previous post -- I take it that was incorrect?

Comment: And the breaker size mentioned in the question is 125A. while here you say 100A. You also said it was 20 ft and now you say 1 ft. Please edit your question to have the complete, correct, information in the question itself.